# What are the advantages and disadvantages of becoming a werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Before I decide whether or not I would like to become a werewolf, I'd like to know what I'll have to deal with. Whether this means being stronger, or having an appetite for human flesh, what are the advantages and disadvantages associated with becoming a werewolf?

I'm particularly interested in if there are any difference between the different races when they become werewolves. For instance, is there any difference between if an orc becomes a werewolf, to if a Khajiit becomes a werewolf?

Comment: I can already see that Skyrim is going to be fertile ground for hilarious-sounding questions.

Comment: I can proudly say that I am a Khajiit Werewolf, and it's clearly better than any other race. [Proof](http://www.cs.brown.edu/orgs/artemis/old/1998/participants/sipsy/isn_catdog.gif)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While in regular form, there isn't a whole lot of difference between werewolves and non-werewolves, but when you transform, you get a ton of benefits and drawbacks:

#### Benefits

- Increased max health by 100 (non-regenerating)
- Increased max stamina by 100
- Faster sprint speed
- Wolves no longer attack you
- Committing crimes in beast form don't count against your normal form
- Immunity to all diseases, including vampirism (also [cures vampirism if you have it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34905/how-exactly-does-lycanthropy-work-does-it-mix-with-vampirism/35183#35183))
- Special, werewolf-only abilities like howls

#### Drawbacks

- No looting (when a werewolf)
- No inventory or equipment access (when a werewolf)
- No talking (when a werewolf)
- People either run away from you, cower, or attack you (no friendly humanoid NPCs) (when a werewolf)
- If someone sees you transform, it's automatically a crime
- No rested bonus
- If caught transforming in public it's 1,000 gold bounty to pay

Comment: i hear you are also vunerable to silver weapons, though im not sure if this is just in beast form or in human form, too

Comment: It appears you cannot become a vampire once a werewolf, even after curing the werewolf-ism. This last one might be a bug though.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that characters that can transform into werewolves will **never** get the rested bonus.  The current wording of the answer implies that the rested bonus is only removed when in werewolf form.

Comment: The real drawback is that your armor does nothing in beast form, so you will likely die in 1 hit past level 15.

Answer (score 3):

You can become a werewolf once per day for a couple of real-time minutes.  It's excellent for serial killing of low-to-medium-level humanoids (like the Markarth prison), or for the fun of causing a major crime if caught transforming in sight.

When you have the beast blood, you cannot get diseases.  The only disadvantages are that you can never get the "restful sleep" bonuses, and you are doubly vulnerable to silver weapon attacks.  So I recommend that you get the beast blood through the Champions quest chain in Whiterun unless you're going straight through the main quest.

Answer (score 2):

IGN's wiki has [a good breakdown](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim/Lycanthropy?objectid=93395).

From this page, I can only find one drawback besides the fact that once you are in beast mode certain companions might leave you, and most people will react negatively to you being a werewolf. That drawback is that you cannot use the Rest buff after sleeping, which normally gives you a 5% boost in leveling up skills for 8 hours. It doesn't seem like different classes react differently to becoming werewolves.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a werewolf silver weapons do slightly more damage to you than they normally would. This isn't anything you have to worry about though.

However, in beast form silver weapons do double the amount of damage. But really the only people who have silver weapons are werewolf hunters (who are called Silverhand).