# How can I be more athletic?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Now that the athletics and acrobatics skills have disappeared, is there a way to run faster or to jump higher in Skyrim?

Comment: I don't have the answer but Alteration Magic might prove useful.

Comment: Meh, drink enough Skooma and you can THINK you are faster and stronger. +1 for a good question though. Does anyone know is increasing stamina or health affects this? Those would be my guess if the magic side doesn't offer anything.

Comment: @Jclaspill increasing stamina will help as far as being able to sprint for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There aren't very many (if any) ways to increase your speed permanently or in a traditional manner: looks like Bethesda scrapped that entirely. However, there are a few non-convential and temporary means to increase it:

#### Sprinting

The basic way to increase your speed is to sprint. Since sprinting uses stamina, increasing your stamina, as [Arkive mentions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35161/how-can-i-be-more-athletic#comment-51371), or your stamina regeneration rate will allow you to move faster for longer periods of time:

- Choose **Stamina** while leveling up
- Use potions and equip armor with the [**Regenerate Stamina**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Regenerate_Stamina) effect
- The **Wind Walker** perk in the [*Light Armor* tree](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Light_Armor) will increase stamina regeneration while wearing all light armor
- Using the  [**Become Ethereal** shout](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Become_Ethereal) will prevent your stamina from depleting while sprinting, further increasing your sprint time.

You can also sprint with your horse, although it doesn't appear to be any faster than regular sprinting.

#### Lycanthropy

If you want to run even faster, contract lycanthropy. [In beast form](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-becoming-a-werewolf/35254#35254), you sprint much, much faster than normal.

#### Shouts

While not strictly allowing you to run faster or leap higher, there are a few shouts that accomplish nearly the same thing:

- [**Slow Time**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Slow_Time) will let you—aptly—slow time to allow you to move normally within your frame of reference but much quicker in others.
- [**Whirlwind Sprint**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Whirlwind_Sprint) is an extremely fast sprint that almost acts as a "blink" spell or short-range teleport.

#### Archery

If you happen to be investing in the [*Archery* skill](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archery), you can pick up the **Ranger** perk, which will increase your movement speed while drawing your bow.

#### Minimizing slowness

If you exceed your carrying capacity, you'll no longer move at normal speed. So—while not technically a speed increase—if you want to ensure you stay at your speed, you'll want to carry less stuff or increase your carrying capacity:

- Choosing **Stamina** when leveling up increases your capacity by 5 points
- Activating the **Steed Stone** will increase your capacity by 100 points
- Choosing the **Many Pockets** perk in the [*Pickpocket* tree](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pickpocket) will also increase your capacity by 100 points

Additionally, you can negate the weight effects of your armor, thus maximizing your carrying capacity:

- The **Conditioning** perk in the [*Heavy Armor tree*](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Heavy_Armor) will negate the weight effects of heavy armor
- The **Unhindered** perk in the *Light Armor* tree will negate the weight effects of light armor
- The [**Steed Stone**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Standing_Stone) will negate the weight effects of *any* armor you wear.

If all else fails and you're still overencumbered, riding a horse will negate the effects of overencumberence while mounted.

Finally, wearing heavy armor comes with a hit to speed. You can mitigate this by wearing light armor, taking the **Conditioning** perk, or, as [Hafax mentions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/37419/3389), activating the **Steed Stone**.

Comment: That's a plain great answer! Where did you find all the information? All by yourself?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The details about skills and abilities is from play-testing and [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/) (links in answer).

Answer (score 2):

Stone of the Steed removes speed penalties from equipment.

Comment: About to say that, dammit. +1

Answer (score 1):

Speed is determined by your fatigue. and of course weight.

Comment: Fatigue doesn't exist in Skyrim. Perhaps you meant Stamina?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Elemental Fury shout, while sprinting with a dagger, and doing run attacks. The faster attacking makes your running faster. It is quite effective, I tested it myself.