# Pro's and cons of being a vampire/werewolf in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What are the pro's and cons of choosing to be vampire or werewolf in skyrim. Also if there are any differences between the original game and the dlc (regarding the pro's and cons).

Also what situational advantages/disadvantages would a werewolf have in close quarters / ranged / stealth / etc combat compared to the advantages/disadvantages of a vampire.

I also read something about being a vampire/werewolf would restrict you access to certain cities? Does this differ between vampire/werewolf?

Would chosing werewolf/vampire impact quests that you already started? Would it cause some of your followers to stop helping you?

The accepted answer it that which provides an overview of stats and/or effects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the advantages and disadvantages of becoming a vampire?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35257/4797) and [What are the advantages and disadvantages of becoming a werewolf?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/34896/4797)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Werewolves**

Pros

> - Immunity to disease (human form)
> - Max health increase (100 points)
> - Max stamina increase (100 points)
> - Increased speed (faster than horses)
> - Wolves treat you as an ally
> - Any crimes you commit as a werewolf do not add to your bounty as a human
> - Increased melee damage
> - Improved dexterity (jump a lot farther)
> - Special abilities called howls
>
>   1. Fear to enemies level 25 and below for 30 seconds
>   2. Detects life in a large area around your character for 60 seconds
>   3. Summons two wolves to fight with you; you get these howls through companion quests

Cons

> - You cannot receive a bonus from being rested while in human form, and while you are in werewolf form: you cannot pick up any items (this
>     includes looting corpses)
> - All human form powers, weapons, and armor are unusable in werewolf form and vice versa
> - You cannot talk
> - Citizens are scared of you (they either flee or attack you on sight)
> - If anyone sees you transform it is considered a major crime.

**Vampires**

Pros

> - Immunity to disease
> - Immunity to poison
> - Illusion spells do more damage (25%)
> - You are harder to detect (only while sneaking; 25%)
> - Resistance to frost (25% multiplied by the stage you are at)
> - There are an array of new vampire powers
>
>   1. Vampire's sight allows you to see in dark environments
>   2. Vampiric drain saps life from your opponent (damage=stage+1)
>   3. Vampire's servant allows you to reanimate a creature for 60 seconds (the higher the stage the stronger the creatures/people you
>        can reanimate)
>   4. Vampire's seduction keeps level 8 and lower enemies from fighting and fleeing
>   5. Embrace of shadows allows you to turn invisible for 180 seconds).

Cons

> - People hate you when you are in stage 4 and will attack you
> - When outdoors during the day health, magicka, and stamina are all decreased and do not regenerate (15 multiplied by the stage)
> - Weakness to fire 25% multiplied by the stage
> - You will need to feed on humans to keep on a low stage otherwise you cannot interact with humans (this leads to making your own
>     weapons, armor, and potions)

**Skyrim's Dawnguard DLC**

> You have the upgraded powers of a Vampire Lord to bring into battle.
>   Werewolves have been buffed slightly too, enabling you to unlock new
>   abilities and upgrade those that you already have.

- Added 2 skill trees

  - Vampire Lord Skill Tree
  - Werewolf Skill Tree

These perks can only be unlocked through special means - namely, feeding on corpses as a Vampire or Werewolf.

**Vampire Lord Skill Tree**

> - Power Of The Grave - 50 point bonus to health, magicka and stamina as Vampire Lord
> - Detect All Creatures - Night Power: Detect all creatures, even Dwarven Automatons. Requires Power Of The Grave.
> - Mist Form - Night Power: Transform into an invulnerable mist, while health, magicka and stamina regenerate. Requires Detect All Creatures.
> - Supernatural Reflexes - Night Power: Everything slows down while you move faster. Requires Mist Form.
> - Vampiric Grip - Blood Magic: Can pull a creature to your from a distance, and do choking damage once it's close. Requires Power Of The
>     Grave.
> - Summon Gargoyle - Blood Magic: Can conjure a gargoyle to fight for you. Requires Vampiric Grip.
> - Corpse Curse - Blood Magic: Target is paralysed. Requires Summon Gargoyle.
> - Blood Healing - Killing a person with a power attack bite restores all your health. Requires Power Of The Grave.
> - Unearthly Will - Night Powers and Blood Magic cost 33% less. Requires Power Of The Grave.
> - Poison Talons - Melee attacks do 20 points of poison damage. Requires either Blood Healing or Unearthly Will.
> - Night Cloak - In combat you are surrounded by a cloud of bats that feed on enemies within melee range.

**Werewolf Skill Tree**

> - Bestial Strength - Do 25% more damage as a Werewolf. Has four upgrade possibilities.
> - Totem Of Ice Brothers - Werewolf Totem Of Brotherhood howl now calls Ice Wolves. Requires Bestial Strength.
> - Totem Of The Moon - Werewolf Totem Of Brotherhood howl now calls Werewolves. Requires Totem Of Ice Brothers.
> - Totem Of The Predator - Werewolf Totem Of The Hunt howl has extended range and sows whether targets are not in combat, searching
>     or actively in combat. Requires Bestial Strength.
> - Totem Of Terror - Howl Of Terror affects even higher level creatures. Requires Bestial Strength.
> - Animal Vigor - 100 point bonus to health and stamina in beast form. Requires Bestial Strength.
> - Gorging - Feeding heals twice as much health. Requires Animal Vigor.
> - Savage Feeding - Able to feed off most dead creatures. Feeding off creatures instead of people only provides half the extended time.

Sources:

http://zzbrent.hubpages.com/hub/Elder-Scrolls-V-Skyrim-Werewolf-or-Vampire
http://www.nowgamer.com/cheats/skyrim-cheats/1452424/skyrim_dawnguard_dlc_guide_vampire_lord_werewolf_skill_trees.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played the vampire DLC, but when you're a werewolf you won't become well rested anymore while sleeping.

While in wolf form, people will either retreat or attack you.

This article on the wiki will tell you more about it: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lycanthropy_%28Skyrim%29

As for becoming a vampire: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vampirism_%28Skyrim%29